# How to select rows from the pandas dataframe with certain conditions

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose the dataframe is as follows:

```
id   class  count
 0     A      2
 0     B      2
 0     C      2
 0     D      1
 1     A      3
 1     B      3
 1     E      2
 2     D      4
 2     F      2
```

For each id, I want to find the class whose count is the maximum. If more than one class have the same count, merge them into one line. For the above example, the result should be as follows:

```
id     class    count
 0     A,B,C      2
 1     A,B        3
 2     D          4
```

How to use a statement in pandas to realize this function?

Answer (score 3):

Solution with [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and [`aggregate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
df = df[g['count'].transform('max').eq(df['count'])]
print (df)
   id class  count
0   0     A      2
1   0     B      2
2   0     C      2
4   1     A      3
5   1     B      3
7   2     D      4

df = df.groupby('id').agg({'class':','.join, 'count':'first'}).reset_index()
print (df)
   id  class  count
0   0  A,B,C      2
1   1    A,B      3
2   2      D      4
```

Another solution with custom function:

```
def f(x):
    x = x[x['count'] == x['count'].max()]
    return (pd.Series([','.join(x['class'].values.tolist()), x['count'].iat[0]], 
                      index=['class','count']))

df = df.groupby('id').apply(f).reset_index()
print (df)
   id  class  count
0   0  A,B,C      2
1   1    A,B      3
2   2      D      4
```

Answer (score 3):

***option 1***

```
s = df.set_index(['id', 'class'])['count']
s1 = s[s.eq(s.groupby(level=0).max())].reset_index()
s1.groupby(
    ['id', 'count']
)['class'].apply(list).reset_index()[['id', 'class', 'count']]

   id      class  count
0   0  [A, B, C]    2.0
1   1     [A, B]    3.0
2   2        [D]    4.0
```

***option 2***

```
d1 = df.set_index(['id', 'class'])['count'].unstack()

v = d1.values
m = np.nanmax(v, 1)
t = v == m[:, None]
pd.DataFrame({
        'id': d1.index,
        'class': [list(s) for s in t.dot(d1.columns)],
        'count': m
    })[['id', 'class', 'count']]

   id      class  count
0   0  [A, B, C]    2.0
1   1     [A, B]    3.0
2   2        [D]    4.0
```